# How to add the namespace in the xml root tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the minimal code I want to add the namespace in the header tag.
 Here is my input XML.Can any one Help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<R>
<M>
<H>1</H>
<B>
    <p Ccy="GBP">1</p>
 </B>
</M>
<M>
 <H>1</H>
 <B>
    <p Ccy="GBP">4</p>
 </B>
 </M>
```

I have tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <R>
        <M>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="M[1]/H | M/B" />
        </M>
    </R>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<R xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 Y:\Data\Dokument\Kommunikation\Layouter\ISO20022\Sche\Pain001\Pain.001.001.03.xsd"
 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
<M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>
        <p Ccy="GBP">1</p>
    </B>
    <B>
        <p Ccy="GBP">4</p>
    </B>
</M>
```

Fiddle https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/38

I have tried to add namespace in the header part.

Comment: Do you want `xsi:schemaLocation` namespaces two times? as you mentioned in Expected output.

Comment: check this : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/39

Comment: Have you tried suggested way in given Fiddle?

Comment: yes I have tried  but the namespace is coming different position.Here is my actual namespace is coming like this.
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 Y:\Data\Dokument\Kommunikation\Layouter\ISO20022\Sche\Pain001\Pain.001.001.03.xsd">                                                                                                         But I want the Xml:schemaLocation first then other.

Comment: You can't control the order of attributes or namespace declarations on an element and the order doesn't matter in XML. So putting the namespace declaration `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` and the attribute (e.g. `xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 foo.xsd"`) on the `R` result element is fine and the right way to introduce them into the result.