# Add the namespace in the xml root tag

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the minimal code I want to add the namespace in the header tag. Here is my input XML.Can any one Help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<R>
<M>
<H>1</H>
<B>
<p Ccy="GBP">1</p>
</B>
</M>
<M>
<H>1</H>
<B>
<p Ccy="GBP">4</p>
</B>
</M>
```

I have tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
<R>
    <M>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="M[1]/H | M/B" />
    </M>
</R>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
<R xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 Y:\Data\Dokument\Kommunikation\Layouter\ISO20022\Schema\Pain001\pain.001.001.03.xsd"> 
  <M> 
    <H>1</H> 
    <B> 
      <p Ccy="GBP">1</p> 
    </B> 
    <B> 
      <p Ccy="GBP">4</p> 
    </B> 
  </M>
</R>
```

Fiddle https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbG/41

Comment: I think you forgot to include your expected output.... Thank you!

Comment: yes My out put should be     <?xml version="1.0"?>                                                    <R xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03
Y:\Data\Dokument\Kommunikation\Layouter\ISO20022\Schema\Pain001\pain.001.001.03.xsd">    <M>
    <H>1</H>
    <B>
        <p Ccy="GBP">1</p>
    </B>
    <B>
        <p Ccy="GBP">4</p>
    </B>
</M>

Comment: How does this question differ from your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177339/how-to-add-the-namespace-in-the-xml-root-tag)? As Martin Honnen said in comments in the previous question, you cannot control the order of attributes and namespace declarations, and the order doesn't really matter anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="2.0" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <R xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03 Y:\Data\Dokument\Kommunikation\Layouter\ISO20022\Schema\Pain001\pain.001.001.03.xsd">
            <M>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="M[1]/H | M/B" />
            </M>
        </R>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
Chek it.
```